# How can I plot a specific profile from rotated data on contourf or pcolormesh graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, image-rotation, contourf

I have an image stored in a numpy array.  I have created a function to rotate that data by an angle theta.  To perform the rotation the function converts the index coordinates of the image (i,j) to (x,y) and applies a rotation matrix.  Then the function returns a meshgrid for the rotated (X, Y) coordinates.

I would like to overlay the non-rotated image and the rotated image on the same coordinate system and extract specific vertical & horizontal profiles.  I cannot navigate the rotated image properly because it can only be navigated with 'ij' using the map_coordinates function(as far as I know).

Setup and function definitions:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

```
def rotate_image(arr, dpi, theta_degrees = 0.0, pivot_point = [0,0]):

  theta_radians = (np.pi/180.0)* theta_degrees
  c = round(np.cos(theta_radians), 3)
  s = round(np.sin(theta_radians), 3)

  rotation_matrix = np.array([[c, -s, 0],
                              [s, c, 0],
                              [0, 0,  1]])
  #print(rotation_matrix)

  width, height = arr.shape
  pivot_point_xy = np.array([(25.4 / dpi[0])* pivot_point[0], (25.4/dpi[1])*pivot_point[1]])
  pivot_shift_vector = np.array([[pivot_point_xy[0]],
                                 [pivot_point_xy[1]],
                                 [0]])
  
  x = (25.4 / dpi[0]) * np.array(range(width)) #convert pixels to mm units
  y = (25.4 / dpi[1]) * np.array(range(height))#convert pixels to mm units
  
  XX , YY = np.meshgrid(x,y)
  ZZ = arr
  coordinates = np.stack([XX,YY,ZZ])
  #shift to rotation point, apply rotation, shift back to original coordinates
  coordinates_reshape = np.reshape(coordinates, (3,-1))
  translated_coordinates = coordinates_reshape - pivot_shift_vector
  rotated_coordinates = np.matmul(rotation_matrix, translated_coordinates)
  final_coordinates = rotated_coordinates + pivot_shift_vector
  final_coordinates_reshaped = np.reshape(final_coordinates, (3, width, height))
  
  return final_coordinates_reshaped
```

Example plots:

```
img = np.arange(1,26).reshape((5,5))

rotated_img_0 = rotate_image(img, theta_degrees= 0, dpi =[1,1], pivot_point = [2.5,2.5])
rotated_img_1 = rotate_image(img, theta_degrees= 45, dpi =[1,1], pivot_point = [2.5,2.5])

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize = (10,20))

ax[0].pcolormesh(*rotated_img_0, vmin=0, vmax=rotated_img_0[2].max())
ax[0].pcolormesh(*rotated_img_1, vmin=0, vmax=rotated_img_1[2].max(), alpha = 0.7)
ax[0].hlines(60, rotated_img_1[0].min(), rotated_img_1[0].max() , color = 'black')

ax[1].contourf(*rotated_img_0, vmin=0, vmax=rotated_img_0[2].max())
ax[1].contourf(*rotated_img_1, vmin=0, vmax=rotated_img_1[2].max(), alpha = 0.7)
ax[1].hlines(60, rotated_img_1[0].min(), rotated_img_1[0].max() , color = 'black')

plt.show()
```

I tried to adapt from scipy the interpolate2d methods outlined here but it doesn't work on rotated data: https://docs.scipy.org/doc//scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html

Map_coordinates also works on the non-rotated data using 'ij' coordinates.  Simple slicing of i,j would also be ok for my purposes.

I would like to be able to extract the same profile from each chart at the same xy coordinates.  [image: Example of the output of the included code. Extract profiles shown by horizontal line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this isn't a direct answer I decided that it was best to go around the problem.  I rewrote the rotate_image function so that simple array slicing can be used to extract the profiles using map_coordinates function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage

def rotate_image(img, theta_degrees = 0.0, pivot_point = np.array([[0], 
[0]])):

    width , height = img.shape

    #compute the 2D rotation matrix
    theta_radians = (np.pi/180.0)* theta_degrees
    c = round(np.cos(theta_radians), 3)
    s = round(np.sin(theta_radians), 3)

    rotation_matrix = np.array([[c, -s],
                          [s, c]])

    #create a sampling point cloud using meshgrid
    X, Y = range(width), range(height)
    XX , YY = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    coordinates = np.stack([XX, YY])
    coordinates_reshape = np.reshape(coordinates, (2,-1))

    #rotate the image around the chosen pivot point
    translated_coordinates = coordinates_reshape - pivot_point
    rotated_coordinates = np.matmul(rotation_matrix, 
      translated_coordinates)
    final_coordinates = rotated_coordinates + pivot_point
    final_coordinates_reshaped = np.reshape(final_coordinates, (2, width, 
              height))

    #use scipy map_coordinates function to resample the image at the new 
    #coordinates
    rotated_image = ndimage.map_coordinates(img, 
                     final_coordinates_reshaped, mode = 'constant')

    return rotated_image

img = np.random.rand(100, 100)*100

rotated_img = rotate_image(img, 20, np.array([[50],[50]]))

#graph Results
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[0].imshow(rotated_img)
ax[0].hlines(50, 0, 99)
ax[1].plot(rotated_img[50])
```

[image]